# Multidot extension for SaveFileDialog in C#?

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

Basically I'm trying to set the SaveFileDialog's filter like let's say to... "Xml Document (*.asdf.xml)|*.asdf.xml".  It'll filter the files correctly when picking a file, but when actually saving the file it only saves as a ".xml".  Is this even supported?

I also can't think of a suitable workaround as most workarounds seem to involve needing to manually change the filename without the user knowing about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true;

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
sfd.Filter = "XML File (*.asdf.xml)|*.asdf.xml|All Files|";
sfd.SupportMultiDottedExtensions = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a stab at creating a quick win form using the SaveFileDialog and I was able to get a file to save with a multi-dot extension without issue.  I'm using VS2010 and C#.  Here's my code for a button click event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Xml Document (.asdf.xml)|*.asdf.xml";
    saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    System.IO.FileStream fs = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile() as System.IO.FileStream;

    fs.Write(new byte[] { }, 0, 0);
    fs.Close();
}
```

It worked whether my filter used `*.asdf.xml` or `.asdf.xml`.

How is your code different?  If it's the same, are you creating a new file or overwriting an existing one?  I'm not sure what else would be different without seeing your code.

EDIT/UPDATE: Just saw sgrassie's answer about setting SupportMultiDottedExtension.  I didn't set it, so maybe it defaults to true in C#/.NET 4.

HTH!